# Can I randomly generate numbers without the same number next to eachother?

Tags: python

My goal is to generate a series of random numbers without allowing the same number repeating next to eachother but allowing the same number twice like `1,2,1,2` but not `1,1,2,2` and I'm just not really sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Generate a random number, check if it is the same as the previous one. If it is discard the number and try again, ....

Comment: Create a list of numbers you want to select. (This will probably a range). Then select a number from this list. For the second time, remove this number from the list and select another. Create the range again and remove the last number again and so on..

Comment: More complicated way: If e. g. you generate numbers from "range(10)" and last number was 6, generate from "range(9)" and if result is 6 or greater, add 1.

Comment: @Wimanicesir The question explicitely states that numbers may be drawn several times. Your solution solves a different problem.

Comment: Do you need a specific randomness or other feature that sets apart possible solutions? There are tons of ways to approach this, from resampling to just post-processing the result.

Comment: @ypnos, No it isn't. You create the range every time again and only remove the last chosen result :). Please read it correctly before making comments ;)

Comment: @Wimanicesir I understand your comment better now. Note that I had read your comment and replied to it before you edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import random
list = []
list.append(random.randrange(50))
for i in range(50):
    x = random.randrange(50)
    while x == list[i]:
        x = random.randrange(50)
    list.append(x)
print(list)
```

Also you should post your own attempt. It gives everyone a good reference and starting point to help you out in a meaning full and focused way.